# Change Access Report control source on Load

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a Report based on a crosstab query. The problem I have is the number of fields will vary between 1 - 18 depending on the timeline requested and the number of months we have data for. I want to set the fields as sources in the proper controls ahead of time, so I tried to build them in conditionally with vba. I tried writing this code in onload event but it's not working. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

```
Me.Month6.ControlSource = IIf(llreportcrosstab.TotalMonths.Value >= 6, "llreportcrosstab.6", "llreportcrosstab.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building all 18 controls, and setting their .Visible parameter to either True or False depending on how many fields you're actually going to show.

Comment: I have added that to the controls as well but when I run the report with the controls built but not linked to actual fields in the query, I get an error and the report does not generate. I tried building the conditional argument into the property box but it still gives me the same error. I can't force the report to always generate the necessary fields unless i add placeholders for the data that's not there for upcoming months.